# How to share all the properties of two interfaces with the same properties

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have two interfaces and the both have the same exact properties.

Just in case you're wondering why I've got two interfaces like these it's a long story, but yes, it has to be this way.

Based on a condition a List is returned if condition is the other way a List will be returned.

By looking at my interfaces and my code below I need to be able to make use of one object, in other words if doesn't matter which interface is returned I need to be able to work with one object and not looping one List interface and setting properties of the other.

I need something like this

```
compParts = genCompParts;
```

--- Code usage

```
    public class ComponentParts : IComponentParts
    {
        public ComponentParts() { }
        public ComponentParts(Guid userID, int compID, bool isGeneric)
        {
            List<IComponentPart> compParts = null;
            List<IComponentPart_Max> genCompParts = null;

            if (isGeneric)
            {
                genCompParts = GenericCatalogBL.GenericCatalogManagerBL.GetComponentPartsMax(compID);
            }
            else
            {
                compParts = CatalogManagerDL.GetComponentParts(userID, compID);
            }

            var verParts = compParts.Where(x => x.CompTypeName.ToLower().Contains("vertical"));
            if (verParts.Count() > 0) { this.Vertical = verParts.ToList<IComponentPart>(); }

            var horParts = compParts.Where(x => x.CompTypeName.ToLower().Contains("horizontal"));
            if (horParts.Count() > 0) { this.Horizontal = horParts.ToList<IComponentPart>(); }

//... redundant code omitted
```

**---Interface Snapshots---**

[image: Interface Snapshots]

---

I ended up creating a class library call Interfaces and I just share those interfaces across different programs in my solution.

**It's what I should of done in the first place, just being lazy.**

Comment: I would think you'd want the _Max interface to implement the other... otherwise there really isn't any valid conversion. You said they're designed this way for a good reason, though, so maybe you should just write some extension method to convert between them?

Comment: You say "it has to be this way". Why? Having two identical interfaces is silly, especially given that those are *very* specific interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The totally brute-force way, assuming you don't own either `IComponentPart` or `IComponentPart_Max` and can't fix one of them.

Make a new interface that you control

```
interface IComponentPart {
    string BrandGroup {get; set;}
    int BrandID {get; set;}
    // ...
}
```

Make wrappers for both of the existing interfaces that adapt them to your interface

```
class IComponentPartWrapper : IComponentPart  {
    private readonly CatelogDL.IComponentPart _underlyingPart;

    public IComponentPartWrapper(CatelogDL.IComponentPart underlyingPart) {
        _underlyingPart = underlyingPart
    }

    public string BrandGroup {
        get {return _underlyingPart.BrandGroup;}
        set {_underlyingPart.BrandGroup = value;}
    }

    public int BrandID {
        get {return _underlyingPart.BrandID ;}
        set {_underlyingPart.BrandID = value;}
    }

    // ...
}

class IComponentPart_MaxWrapper : IComponentPart  {
    private readonly GenericCatalogDL.IComponentPart_Max _underlyingPart;

    public IComponentPartWrapper(GenericCatalogDL.IComponentPart_Max underlyingPart) {
        _underlyingPart = underlyingPart
    }

    public string BrandGroup {
        get {return _underlyingPart.BrandGroup;}
        set {_underlyingPart.BrandGroup = value;}
    }

    public int BrandID {
        get {return _underlyingPart.BrandID ;}
        set {_underlyingPart.BrandID = value;}
    }

    // ...
}
```

Make your code use your interface, and wrap the results from either library in the corresponding wrapper

```
public class ComponentParts : IComponentParts
{
    public ComponentParts() { }
    public ComponentParts(Guid userID, int compID, bool isGeneric)
    {
        List<IComponentPart> compParts;

        if (isGeneric)
        {
            compParts = GenericCatalogBL.GenericCatalogManagerBL.GetComponentPartsMax(compID)
                .Select(x => new IComponentPart_MaxWrapper(x))
                .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            compParts = CatalogManagerDL.GetComponentParts(userID, compID)
                .Select(x => new IComponentPartWrapper(x))
                .ToList();
        }

        // ...
```